# In c++ what does this mean: for string n and int l n[l]=-1;

Tags: c++, string

Here is the whole code:

```
    string n,w;
    char max='0';
    int l=0,p,i,k,j;

    cin>>n>>k;

    p=n.length();
    for (i=0;i<p-k;i++){
        max='0';
        for (j=l;j<p-(p-k)+1+i;j++){
             if (n[j]>max) {
                  l=j;
                  max=n[j];
                }
          }

        n[l]=-1;
        w[i]=max;
        cout<<w[i];
    }
```

I tried to rewrite the code in java but couldn't figure out what that n[l]=-1 means.
And please don't mind the other aspects of this code.

Comment: C++ has operator overloading. `std::string` has a member function `char operator[]( size_t )` which returns the character at a specific location in a string. See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/

Comment: Edit to above, it is actually `char& operator[]( size_t )` (or a const version of that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more than likely setting the byte to `0xFF` (which is equal to `-1` as a signed byte).